# How Vault agent solves Secret Zero challenge in Kubernetes?

Tags: secrets-management, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

HashiCorp Vault Agent creates a sidecar that talks to Vault server and injects secrets as files into containers. The agent presumably uses Kubernetes Service Account in some way. But ultimately there must be a secret zero somewhere, protected somehow, and I would like to understand how it works.

What does Vault Agent use to authenticate with Vault Server, and how is that stored on disk, protected by what?

Comment: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector-csi states: "[Both Agent Injection and Vault CSI solutions] leverage the application’s Kubernetes pod service account token as [Secret Zero](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/secret-zero-mitigating-the-risk-of-secret-introduction-with-vault) to authenticate with Vault via the Kubernetes auth method." The Kubernetes service account token is a JWT token created using the Kubernetes API, signed by a private key owned by the API server. However, I think I have the same question to you: is this not yet another secret that could be stolen?

Comment: That probably means it is protected by the OS account the API server runs under.

Comment: That's true; however I'd expect the same to be true of a static key used to configure encryption-at-rest of native K8s secrets - which seems to be not recommended! (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/#understanding-the-encryption-at-rest-configuration)